# Placing small image button on right corner of a image

Tags: android

I am able to take the pictures and put it grid view but, Has a picture is taken i want to place small image button on right corner of a image.

Comment: can you post your gridview item xml?

Comment: post your item layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ..

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
android:layout_width="134dp"
android:layout_height="121dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:src="@drawable/antartica1" />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/buttonanimation"
android:layout_margin="3dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        >

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageButton 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/image"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I hope this will help you...*

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_width="134dp"
    android:layout_height="121dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/antartica1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/buttonanimation"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Please use this layout in your Adapter*

Answer (score -1):

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15px"
            android:background="@drawable/chatbtn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_conduct_pd_txt_chat_counter_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/msg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

add My image:
[image]

add other image:
[image]

i hope this is useful for you...